# Loop em javascript não adiciona propriedade do objeto

Tags: javascript, loop

segue meu código

```
    var canvasEvents = new Object;  

    canvasEvents['05-30-2015'] = '<a href="#" target=_blank>CAMPEONATOS SUL-AMERICANOS DE ATLETISMO</a>';

    $.getJSON('http://www.atletismope.com.br/eventos/lista',  function(eventos) {

         $.each(eventos, function(index, evento) {

              canvasEvents["04-20-2015"] = '<a href="#" target=_blank>CAMPEONATOS SUL-AMERICANOS DE ATLETISMO</a>';
         });    

    });

    canvasEvents["04-25-2015"] = '<a href="#" target=_blank>CAMPEONATOS SUL-AMERICANOS DE ATLETISMO</a>';
```

Quando canvasEvents é adicionado dentro do looping não funciona, mas se adicionamos fora do looping funciona. Por que?

Existe um plugin que usa esse objeto, o jquery.calendario.js. A atribuição do objeto só funciona se eu colocar um alert fora do loop. Aqui está o código que está funcionando. Podem visualizar o resultado nesta url: http://www.atletismope.com.br/eventos/calendario

```
var canvasEvents = new Object;

$.getJSON('http://www.atletismope.com.br/eventos/lista',  function(eventos) {

    $.each(eventos, function(index, evento) {
        var data = evento.data;
        var data_f = data.substr(5,2) + '-' + data.substr(8,2) + '-' + data.substr(0,4);

        canvasEvents[data_f] = '<a href="#" target=_blank>'+ evento.titulo +'</a>';

    }); 

});

alert(canvasEvents); //nao funciona sem o alert
```

Comment: tem certeza que o código chega a ser executado dentro do loop?

Comment: Jonas vi que colocaste uma resposta seguindo a minha ideia/sugestão de colocar o código dentro da callback. FIco contente que tenhas resolvido o problema. Se quiseres podes marcar como aceite uma das respostas.

Answer (score 3):

O `$.getJSON` é assincrono. Ele faz uma chamada ao servidor e o código a seguir a `$.getJSON` continua a corer. Quando o servidor responder **só então** o código que está dentro de `$.getJSON` é corridor.

Se precisas de correr código com essa informação que o `$.getJSON` retorna (`eventos`)então tens de colocar o código dentro da callback, ou seja dentro desta função:

```
 $.getJSON('http://www.atletismope.com.br/eventos/lista',  function(eventos) {
```

Ou seja só podes usar esse objeto canvas com os dados que lhe são inseridos via `$.getJSON` dentro do próprio `$.getJSON`, apesar de visualmente parecer que a ultima linha do teu exemplo será a ultima a correr.

Answer (score 0):

A chamada do plugin carregava o objeto antes do retornto do $.getJSON, mas por algum motivo se eu desse um alert no objeto forçava a chamada a pegar o objeto carregado com as datas. Bom o que eu fiz foi colocar a chamada do plugin dentro do $getJSON e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

```
    $.getJSON('http://www.atletismope.com.br/eventos/lista',  function(eventos) {

        $.each(eventos, function(index, evento) {
            var data = evento.data;
            var data_f = data.substr(5,2) + '-' + data.substr(8,2) + '-' + data.substr(0,4);

            canvasEvents[data_f] = '<a href="#" target=_blank>'+ evento.titulo +'</a>';


        }); 



    //alert(canvasEvents); //nao funciona sem o alert   

        var cal = $( '#calendar' ).calendario( {
            onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {
                for( var key in dateProperties ) {

                    console.log( key + ' = ' + dateProperties[ key ] );

                }
            },

            caldata : canvasEvents

        } ),

        $month = $( '#calendar-month' ).html( cal.getMonthName() ),
        $year = $( '#calendar-year' ).html( cal.getYear() );



        $( '#calendar-next' ).on( 'click', function() {

            cal.gotoNextMonth( updateMonthYear );

        });

        $( '#calendar-prev' ).on( 'click', function() {

            cal.gotoPreviousMonth( updateMonthYear );

        });

        $( '#calendar-current' ).on( 'click', function() {
            cal.gotoNow( updateMonthYear );
        });


        function updateMonthYear() {
            $month.html( cal.getMonthName() );
            $year.html( cal.getYear() );
        }
    });
```