# Como usar um contador em variável global?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Clique para testar!](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d4h0ykj9/)

O meu objectivo é que a variável count obtenha o valor que vai acumular na função arrayVec1, mas ao invés disso obtenho sempre o resultado 0.
Alguém me pode dizer como consigo passar o valor para fora da função e atribuir à variavel global?

Código:

```js
//cout if exits
var count=0;

var vec = new Array(); 
var vec1= new Array();
var tag1="wedding ball evening gown";
arrayVec();
 

function arrayVec() {
$.getJSON("http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=soccer&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
        function (jd) {            
            for (var i = 0; i < jd.items.length; i++) {
                vec.push(jd.items[i]);  
            }          
            arrayVec1();              
        });
} 

function arrayVec1() {
 for (var i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {         
         $.getJSON('http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags='+"ball"+'&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
         function (jd) {  
            for (var i = 0; i < jd.items.length; i++) {
                  if (tag1 ===  jd.items[i].tags) {
                    count++;                   
                   }
            }                   
                          
        });
     
    }       
} 

alert(count);
```

Comment: Possivel duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60852/129

Comment: Possivel duplicata também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58566/129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ana, o problema é que o `$.getJSON` é assincrono.

O valor de `count` vai ser mudado como tu esperas mas **depois** do teu `alert`. Ou seja, o `$.getJSON` vai correr paralelamente, assincrono, e vai dar resposta depois de script ter chamado o alert.

Tens de usar o count dentro dessa callback do `$.getJSON`. Podes por exemplo testar:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert(count);
}, 1000);
```

[e vais ver](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d4h0ykj9/1/) que esse 1 segundo de espera já vão mostrar o `count` com o novo valor.

O `count` vai ter o valor final na linha a seguir a este loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jd.items.length; i++) {
```

Se quiseres podes é chamar uma função depois desse loop. Da mesma maneira que funcionaria colocar o `alert(count);` aí, dentro dessa callback.

#### Exemplo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d4h0ykj9/2/